# All my troops have disappeared

Tags: clash-of-clans

All my troops are not on the map when I train them, and my archer towers and wizard towers, etc. have no archers or wizards on them.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a cache error in the game. Usually re-opening the game fixes it, but if not go to Settings > Applications > Application Manager > Clash of Clans > Storage > Clear Cache. This works for Android devices, so if you use an Apple device just navigate to the application in your settings.

If you can't clear the cache/are unable to just restart your phone (or if it doesn't work), re-install the app.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to what Crafter, said since I've seen this myself. I've found that **going between the original base and the builder base and back to home** makes everything reappear. As to avoid clearing caches and doing a quick fix.

Granted the troops are still there and the defense buildings are still fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I've been attacked and the building in question was destroyed during that attack.

The way that I've seen to fix this problem on iOS and Android is to exit to the home screen, force-close the game and reload Clash of Clans.